# Adding Facebook dependency gives error in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, facebook, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add Facebook Authentication to a React Native Application.

1. When I add
   `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'` to the
   `Gradle Scripts | build.gradle (Module: app)` in the
   `dependencies` ,
2. I get a build error as :-

   Error:
   android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for . Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

This is the portion of code it is *probably* referring to , which already has an `android:exported`

```
<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
 <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken" android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

</application>
```

This is the portion in the build.gradle

```
//noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:latest.release'

debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
    exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

FB broke this in their latest release.

Change your import to

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:14.1.1'
```